# Property “bounds” not found in tableviewCell Class

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

i need to set top and bottom border in my textField . i am sorry to my  lack of knowledge . so any one help me how can i doing workable `bounds` property this code i set in the tableviewCell class  to crated a TextField .

```
class NewAdressForGustCell : UITableViewCell{

       var areaTextField : RightPaddingTextField = {

            var textField = RightPaddingTextField()

            let topBorder = CALayer()
            topBorder.frame = CGRect(0, 0, bounds.size.width, 1)
            topBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            textField.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)

            let bottomBorder = CALayer()
            bottomBorder.frame = CGRect(0, bounds.size.height-1, bounds.size.width, 1)
            bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
            textField.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)

            textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return textField

        }()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `bounds` implicitly means `self.bounds`, and you cannot refer to `self` (even implicitly) in code where you are in the middle of *initializing* a property of `self`, as you are doing here. This makes sense, because at this time `self` is exactly what does not yet exist: we are still in the middle of initializing it.

One simple workaround is to mark this `var areaTextField` as `lazy`. This works because it guarantees that the code will not run until *after* `self` has been fully initialized. (Note that you must *still* refer *explicitly* to `self`.)

```
class NewAdressForGustCell : UITableViewCell{

    lazy var areaTextField : RightPaddingTextField = {

        var textField = RightPaddingTextField()

        let topBorder = CALayer()
        topBorder.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.bounds.size.width, height:1)
        topBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        textField.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)

        let bottomBorder = CALayer()
        bottomBorder.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:self.bounds.size.height-1, width:self.bounds.size.width, height:1)
        bottomBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        textField.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)

        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return textField

    }()
}
```

Comment: . I was added  `self.bounds` but forget to add var areaTextField as `lazy`

Comment: Yes, you have to do both. I added a working version of your code to my answer! Check the edited answer.

Comment: The general issue you encountered is discussed in my online book here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_properties